# Access values of an variable

Tags: php, arrays, variables

When I do `echo print_r ($var)`, I get:

```
Array
(
    [regular] => stdClass Object
        (
            [1] => 149
            [2] => 154
            [3] => 149
            [4] => 132
            [5] => 159
        )
    [special] => stdClass Object
        (
            [1] => 52
            [2] => 57
            [3] => 48
            [4] => 43
            [5] => 50
        )

)
```

How do I echo the value of "regular 5" of "special 3"?

Comment: It doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

try this;

```
echo $var['regular']->{5};
echo $var['special']->{3};
```

Comment: Perfect! It works! Thanks!